# jQuery Validate Plugin Not Submitting Form

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation

I'm using the jQuery validation plugin from https://jqueryvalidation.org

There is nothing special about the actual form itself, it just uses default markup really.

The issue I have is the form doesn't actually submit on a valid form and requires me to click the submit button again. I've even tried using the `submitHandler` with `form.submit()` too

```
 <form action="/search/" method="post" id="postcode-search">
    <div class="input-wrap">
        <input type="input" id="postcode" name="postcode" class="director-search" placeholder="Enter your Postcode here" required><br>
        <div class="error-message"></div>
    </div>
    <button id="submit" type="submit" class="primary"><span class="inner"><i class="fa fa-search"></i> Search</span></button>
</form>
```

And the code for the form validation is below

```
    $('form#postcode-search').validate({
        rules: {
            postcode: {
                required: true,
                remote: {
                    url: theme_location + 'inc/postcode-validation.php',
                    type: 'post',
                    data: {
                        postcode: function() {
                            return $('input#postcode').val();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        messages: {
            postcode: {
                required: 'Please provide a full postcode.'
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: does the remote validation part work correctly? That seems like the obvious place to start debugging

Comment: Yeah that all works fine, I've even removed the remote validation and it still does the same thing.